# Upper bound to lower bound

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $x(a)\geq1$ and $y(b)\geq1$. I have a relation $x(a) \leq k(a,b)y(b)$ for all $k(a\geq b) \geq 1$ and 
$x(a)=y(b)$ when $k(a=b)=1$. Can we conclude that $x(a)\geq y(b)$ ?

Comment: Parameter $k$ is actually affecting the inequality. I am trying to get $x>y$ in some condition.

Comment: Very confusing. $x,y$ scalars seems to mean they are constants. Second and third sentences seem to mean $x,y$ are functions of $k$. Last sentence, first half suggests they are functions of $k$, but second half makes more sense if they are numbers. Please rewrite question so it makes some sense.

Comment: I have rewritten..Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Are $x, y$ a function of $k$?

Comment: Why do you want this? Where come from $x$ and $y$? What is the context?

Comment: You have rewritten, but you have not fully engaged with my comment. If $x,y$ are functions of $k$, please say so. If they are not functions of $k$, please explain what's meant by "$x=y$ when $k=1$."

Comment: I am really sorry for not able to explain the problem in a nicer way. I have again modified...Hope it works..Thanks to all

Comment: shakera, your two hypothesis seem to be that $x(a)=y(a)$ for every $a$ and that $x(a)\le y(b)$ for every $a\ge b$ (since for positive $u$ and $v$, the hypothesis that $u\le kv$ for every $k\ge1$ is **equivalent** to the fact that $u\le v$). There is no way whatsoever these two hypothesis could imply $x(a)\ge y(b)$ for any $a\ne b$. This is a matter of logic alone (the inequality goes the wrong way), but here is a simple counterexample: choose any positive **decreasing** function $z$ and let $x(a)=y(a)=z(a)$ for every $a$. Can you check this is indeed a counterexample?

Comment: Maybe we could understand the question if you gave an example or two of numbers/functions/whatever $x,y,k$ (and $a$ and $b$?) satisfying the hypotheses of the question, and examples *not* satisfying the hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

No, it most definitely does not imply that. Indeed, try solving for both $x< k y$ and $x \le y$ at the same time for $x \ge 1 \land y \ge 1$.

For $k=2$, $ x = 3$ and $y = 5$ clearly satisfy both: $ 3 < 2 \times 5$ and $3 \le 5$.

Comment: This example does not satisfy that when $k=1$, $x=y$.

Comment: Of course it does not, but your question was specifically formulated for $k>1$.

Comment: It should also satisfy for $k=1$,  $x=y$.